# Why ng g c Command not working in nativeScript + Angular project

Tags: angularjs, nativescript

when i run "ng g c welcome" to generate a new component i get error:
Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace.

i tried running commands:

- tns extension install nativescript-angular-cli
- npm i -g @angular/cli
- npm i -g @nativescript/schematics
- npm i --save-dev @nativescript/schematics
- npm install -D @angular/cli
- npm i @angular-devkit/schematics @angular-devkit/core @schematics/angular

Comment: You should run this command in the same folder when angular.json located

Comment: in nativeScript there is no angular.json file

Answer (score 0):

Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74996251/5276893

In sum. The schematics are no longer supported. You can use component generators through nx, though, which don't rely on angular specifics, or through https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nstudio/angular

Answer (score 0):

run below commands in your project root folder:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli
```

and

```
npm i --save-dev @nativescript/schematics
```

then you need to add an **angular.json** to the root of the project and it should have the following content:

```
{
"version": 1,
"cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@nativescript/schematics"
},
"projects": {
    "my-project-name": {
        "root": "",
        "sourceRoot": "src",
        "projectType": "application",
        "prefix": "ns"
    }
},
"defaultProject": "my-project-name"      }
```

You could update:

**my-project-name** to match the name of your project, but that is not absolutely necessary,

**prefix** to match the prefix for your component selectors (i.e. "prefix": "app" => selector: 'app-home').