# ng add @nativescript/schematics migration attempt failing. Reason: "NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID"

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to run "ng add @nativescript/schematics" to migrate my Angular app to Nativescript for mobile support.

When I run the command, not only does it not generate the .tns files that signify successful conversion, it prints this in the console:

```
√ Packages successfully installed.
NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID
```

It gives very little to go off of. I have tried searching the @nativescript module in the node_modules folder and there is no "id" field to speak of.

Answer (score 1):

`@nativescript/schematics` are deprecated:

> @nativescript/schematics have been deprecated, better alternatives for code-sharing in NativeScript can be explored in the docs https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/schematics

The main way to develop angular web+nativescript projects now is using Nx. The reason being that using the old schematics and having `.tns.ts` and `.tns.html` files ended up very confusing and more often than not introduced a lot of anti-patterns on both NativeScript and web.

So while seemed like a good idea at first, you always ended up with:

```
my.component.ts
my.component.tns.ts
my.component.html
my.component.tns.html
my.module.ts
my.module.tns.ts
```

Essentially reusing 0 lines of code. On top of that, the native application would also follow a "web" approach of nesting a lot of layouts, which are much heavier on native platforms than divs are on the web (https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-angular-performance-tips-tricks/).

In the end you ended up with subpar DX **and** UX on both web and native apps, which are now much easier to solve by using Nx and creating shared libraries for code sharing and platform-specific libraries for everything else.